# Lando - ERROR: No container found for appserver_1

Tags: docker, lando

New to Lando. 
Installed `lando-v3.0.0-beta.44.exe` on `Win10 64`
I am getting an error and hoping to clarify some issues, here is my `.lando.yml`

```
name: myapp
recipe: lamp
config:
  php: 7.2
  webroot: .
  database: 'mariadb:10.0'
```

from `lando start`  everything goes well ... until `ERROR: No container found for appserver_1`

```
Starting landoproxyhyperion5000gandalfedition_proxy_1 ... done
Creating network "myapp_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "myapp_data" with default driver
Creating volume "myapp_appserver" with default driver
Creating volume "myapp_data_database" with default driver
Creating myapp_database_1  ... done
Creating myapp_appserver_1 ... done
Waiting until appserver service is ready...
Waiting until database service is ready...
Waiting until database service is ready...
Waiting until database service is ready...
Waiting until database service is ready...
Waiting until database service is ready...
Waiting until database service is ready...
ERROR: No container found for appserver_1
error: Looks like one of your build steps failed...
warn: This **MAY** prevent your app from working
warn: Check for errors above, fix them, and try again

BOOMSHAKALAKA!!!

Your app has started up correctly.
Here are some vitals:

 NAME            myapp
 LOCATION        C:\Users\username\Documents\htdocs\basicapp
 SERVICES        appserver, database
 APPSERVER URLS  http://myapp.lndo.site
                 https://myapp.lndo.site
```

when I enter `http://myapp.lndo.site` into browser url, I get `Unable to connect`.

Any help would be appreciated as to what this error is about and how to fix it,  thank you.

**EDIT** The fix was to uninstall Docker and Lando, then re-install Docker and install older version of Lando.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you can add your fix as your own answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

When running "lando start" for the first time you might have run [into a bug](https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/1139) that is still being worked on, related to the SSL certificates. You need to run "lando start" a second time and then it might work for you.

Comment: Can you post a link to the Lando issue for this?

Comment: This answer worked for me (2022/05/04) in Lando from Mac (lando-arm64-v3.6.4.dmg).